# Can I use 'RetrieveUpdateAPIView' without 'look_up' field?

Tags: django, http, django-rest-framework, django-views

RetrieveUpdateAPIView's url works with a specific field. (ex. `/profile/update/<pk>`)

I'm getting user account from token in HTTP header, so it's difficult to include user's pk into the url.

This view is my RetrieveUpdateAPIView.

```
class ProfileRetrieveAndUpdateProfile(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileRetrieveAndUpdateSerializer
    # lookup_field = 'pk'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Profile.objects.all()
        logged_in_user_profile = qs.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return logged_in_user_profile
```

Should I just use views.APIView for this feature?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I have the exact same problem now. Thanks!

Comment: Hey I just added a question for you. Vote up!

Comment: Thanks, that's much simpler than what I ended up doing!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved the problem with overriding get_object.

```
def get_object(self):
  queryset = self.get_queryset()
  obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, user=self.request.user)
  return obj
```

Cheers

Comment: It works like a charm. As a side note for people who arrived here trying to get the `request.user` from a JWT implementation. You need to add a custom middleware so that `request.user` is populated. See: https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/master/rest_framework_jwt/authentication.py

Comment: Which middleware should I add? I had similar problem too. I just want to remind it but can't remember

Comment: I have added a custom middleware called `'user_app.middleware.AuthenticationMiddlewareJWT'` (where `user_app.middleware` is the file where I included the code from the github link I provided). Check the answer by AndrewJHart and rserro depending on the Django version.

However, I'm not sure that it is actually required (as I fixed things on the front-end request as well).

Comment: What I am sure though is that the `'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'` is required.